# mdadm - diffference between metadata version

Tags: linux, software-raid, mdadm

Can anyone tell the difference between all the metadata versions for mdadm?

When I try the command `mdadm --examine /dev/sda1`, I can't seem to find `preferred superblocks` on version 1.2.

Is there a way to get this metadata information? Or is `mdadm --examine` just the information I'm going to get?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the following command, the `metadata=1.2` you're seeing refers to the superblock version.

```
root@svr# mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/pool metadata=1.2 UUID=37b2a12f:ea73e45k:32b3efe0:90ac0b2e name=svr:pool
root@svr#
```

There's a [wiki](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats) for the Linux `md` software, and the Version-1 ([Sub-Version 1.2](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_superblock_formats#The_version-1_Superblock_Format)) superblock format are documented pretty well.

However, the best source of documentation would be the source code *itself*. Since the `md` RAID software comes with the Linux kernel, check your kernel-version & visit [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/)

You may also want to find out if your Linux distribution has

1. applied any patches to the Linux kernel source

   - This would make your kernel-source differ from the 'vanilla' Linux kernel code.
2. Find out if they include the the source-code for the kernel they
   distribute.

   - Should be under "`/include/linux/raid/`" somewhere. Look for `md_*.*` files.